# Lock Grafana Library Panels to Disable Editing

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana v8.3.0 and am trying to figure out a way to allow users to add a library panel to their own custom dashboards, but I want to prevent them from being able to edit the library panel. It doesn't seem possible, but maybe I am not seeing the way to do this? Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to restrict the edit and allow add panels at the same time.

You can make the dashboard non-editable by going to Settings -> General turn off the toggle button `Editable`

[image]

Now you won't see add/edit options

Another way is, provisioned the dashboard, user can add/edit but cannot save the changes